# Buffers clipped to features used to create them

Tags: r, sf

I'm trying to create an `sf` object of polygons which are buffer regions clipped to the polygons used to create the buffers. Using `st_difference` returns an `sf` object with all combinations of both `sf` objects. Example below:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

p1<-st_polygon(list(rbind(c(1,1),c(1,2),c(2,2),c(2,1),c(1,1))))
p2<-st_polygon(list(rbind(c(3,1),c(3,2),c(4,2),c(4,1),c(3,1))))

p1p2<-st_sfc(p1,p2)

d<-data.frame(name=c("Poly1","Poly2"))

st_geometry(d)<-p1p2

dBuff<-st_buffer(d,dist=1.5)

dBuffClip<-st_difference(dBuff,d)

dBuffClip
```

I want only these `ggplot()+geom_sf(data=dBuffClip[1,],fill="lightblue")`:

[image]

And none of these `ggplot()+geom_sf(data=dBuffClip[3,],fill="lightblue")`:
[image]

I've realized the I can filter `dBuffClip` using `filter(name==name.1)` but this is very inefficient and crashes my machine because of the size of the data. Does somebody know of an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explode the geometry so you have POLYGON and not MULTIPOLYGON (using `sf::st_cast`) then, you should have a one to one match between feature and buffer. Now, you can apply an iterator (eg., `for`, `lapply`) to subset the feature and corresponding buffer and apply `sf::st_difference`. Results can be combined using `rbind`. This may take awhile with a big dataset but, will keep things memory safe.

Here, lets add the sf package and read in some internal data, which is projected into albers (so we have a real distance). We will then grab 10 random polygons.

```
library(sf)
  d = st_transform(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", 
                   package="sf"), quiet=TRUE),  
                   st_crs(5070))
    d <- d[sample(1:nrow(d), 10),]
```

We then buffer our polygons to 5000m and cast them to POLYGON to ensure that we do not end up with MULTIPOLYGON geometry. This may not always be necessary but, makes things safe.

```
dBuff <- st_cast(st_buffer(d, dist=5000), "POLYGON")  
  plot(st_geometry(dBuff), col="red")
    plot(st_geometry(d), col="white", add=TRUE)
```

Now we can use an iterator to go through each feature and coresponding buffer to create polygon with the source feature erased. For the iterator we use `lapply` and to combine the results we wrap it in `do.call`. The `suppressWarnings` call is to simply suppress an irrelevant warning message.

```
dBuffClip <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) {
  suppressWarnings(st_difference(dBuff[i,], d[i,]))}))
    plot(st_geometry(dBuffClip))
```

With your example

```
d <- st_as_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(1,1),c(1,2), c(2,2),
              c(2,1),c(1,1)))), st_polygon(list(rbind(c(3,1),c(3,2),
              c(4,2),c(4,1),c(3,1))))))

dBuff <- st_cast(st_buffer(d, 1.5), "POLYGON")
  dBuffClip <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) {
        suppressWarnings(st_difference(dBuff[i,], d[i,]))}))

plot(st_geometry(dBuffClip), col=c("green","red"))
```

[image: example result]

Comment: Thank you so much Jeffrey this makes sense and is easy to follow. One question about using `st_cast`. Hypothetically, as long as all of the original geometries are polygons then the buffers created from them should also be polygons, correct? Also, in the case where there were some multipolygon geometries, what would be the issue in using `st_difference`?